# Importing shapefile into a geopackage not working in QGIS 3.24.1

Tags: qgis, shapefile, import, geopackage

Whenever I try to import any kind of .shp file (with any kind of geometry) to any gpkg database, it gives numerous errors, such as:

```
Error 7 Failed to load layer
```

or

```
Error 5
Failed to create fid field (OGR error: Wrong field type for fid)
```

I've tried to import by drag-and-dropping on the navigator and also with the DB manager. Both fail to import.

What could be the issue?

Comment: I think the second error is rather straightforward.

Comment: Try saving to gpkg: right click layer > save/export to Geopackage. Does that work?

Comment: No, if I save the .shp to the .gpkg I want, it gives no errors, however, when I try to import the data from the .gpkg it produces the same result when it returns Error 7 or 5; an empty layer with a "unavailable layer, couldn't find data source" warning.